# How many possible times can one play through Altered Beast?

Tags: altered-beast

In Altered Beast (Sega Genesis version via Wii Virtual Console), my brother and I played through this and got partway through the second run before we died completely. Is there a limit on the number of playthroughs where meaningful changes will occur to the sprites and the gameplay? Or is there a final 'win' that you can attain?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 2 playthroughs is what beats the game.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've beaten Round 5, the game will loop back to Round 1... but on the next higher difficulty. This means that if you beat the game on Normal, you'll have to beat it again on Hard, and then AGAIN on Hardest. On the flip side, you only have to beat the game once if you're good enough to finish Hardest.